# Is there a faster route between Milton Keynes and Cambridge, England than taking a train via London?

Tags: public-transport, england, cambridge

It's ridiculous to find that Google recommends taking a train to London then to Milton Keynes. This really looks like a roundabout route. But I can't find any bus services that are faster than this route. Does anyone have a better idea?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126513/discussion-on-question-by-dr-hope-is-there-a-faster-route-between-milton-keynes).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Short answer: no, there doesn't appear to be a faster route.**

The main bus route from Milton Keynes to Cambridge is the [X5 followed by the 905, operated by Stagecoach](https://www.stagecoachbus.com/promos-and-offers/east/stagecoach-x5). Until recently this was a single bus route, the X5, but it seems this no longer runs the full route.

Google Maps puts this journey at around 2h30, including a 30-minute connection in Bedford. That's slower than the train (1h40) but probably a lot cheaper.

Neither of the two main intercity bus operators, Megabus and National Express, seem to operate this route directly. National Express suggest a 5h connecting itinerary, while Megabus don't seem to serve Milton Keynes at all.

Some time in the future, the [East West Rail project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_West_Rail) may lead to faster trains on this route, but as of 2021 that's nowhere close to completion.

Comment: If you get to Bedford presumably continuing by train to MK is an option.

Comment: Great point @mdewey - I found the bus times by filtering Google Maps to only show buses, so I completely missed that.

Comment: Train from Bedford to MK is an option, but there are no direct trains - change at Bletchley.

Comment: the X5 is also famously unpleasant (at least among residents of Cambridge)

Comment: I am not that much a fan of google maps for travel planning but traveline.info does not find better options.

Comment: I was in Oxford a few weeks ago and found it absolutely incredible that I could not get a train to Cambridge without going into London.
Apparently there was a scheme at one time to build the line but it was cancelled.
To link these two cities by rail would seem more than obvious to me!
This would fix the MK issue as well :-)

Comment: Its worse than this. The route existed until the 1960s. It was then closed down, and parts of the route just East of Bedford were sold off to housing develoipers, so it cannot be reinstated. Blame the infamous Dr. Beeching, and transport ministers of that era.

Comment: The trains from MK to London are frequent and fast (some as little as half an hour). Trains from Kings Cross to Cambridge are also quite fast. London Euston to London Kings Cross is walkable, or a short hop on the tube. So all in all, it's not quite as stupid as it looks. But closing the direct Oxford to Cambridge rail line in the 1960s was!

Comment: If you are determined you might get from MK to Hitchin by bus, from where you can catch trains to Cambridge. Faster? I rather doubt it. The connections won't be timetabled, even if you can rely on a bus being on time.

Answer (score 30):

There used to be a direct bus on this route, the X5 (Oxford - Bicester - Milton Keynes - Bedford - Cambridge), but it was apparently [withdrawn in August 2020](https://www.huntspost.co.uk/news/mayor-of-st-neots-angry-over-changes-to-x5-service-5223438). I haven't travelled this in quite a while, but I used to take the X5 a lot when I was younger.

The [replacement route](https://www.stagecoachbus.com/promos-and-offers/east/east-covid19-services#tab6) seems to be Milton Keynes to Bedford on the X5 (about 25m), and then the 905 from Bedford to Cambridge (about 1h30). The X5 arrives at 15m past the hour and the 905 leaves at 15m and 45m past, so the perfect journey would be about two hours (straight from one to the other) and the longer journey would be about 2h30.

Google Maps suggests the two trains are about 1h45, depending on exact timings, so it does sound like that's the faster option. (The old X5 would have been about 1h50)

Comment: Depending where in the city the OP actually wants to go, it's possible there's a 10 -15 minute advantage (or disadvantage) arriving at  Parkside versus the station, but it doesn't affect the overall message.

Comment: Ironically, the X5 from Cambridge to Oxford was an hourly service that was increased to 30 minutes due to demand, before Covid-19 reduced that demand. The competiton with rail, though, wasn't on journey time but on ticket price.

Comment: Worth noting that the route is particularly unpleasant on a coach if you're prone to motion sickness as there are what seems like endless roundabouts

Comment: @aucuparia Milton Keynes is famed for its many roundabouts.  My experience of Bedford is limited but I seem to recall plenty there too.

Answer (score 29):

Have you considered a taxi?

I'm not sure if that would be considered Public Transport, but there is at least [one MK based company](https://www.twelvetransfers.co.uk/destinations/uk-wide-taxi-transfers/taxi-from-milton-keynes-to-cambridge/) offering a connection 'from 75 GBP'.

This seems comparable to a full-priced, off-peak day single, which is 60.40 GBP [edited; see comment for details] according to [Trainline](https://www.thetrainline.com/book/results?origin=80b48eebb39192459a7c5f4159f3fdd3&destination=e3e04d67118edf0047693508aea3c312&outwardDate=2021-06-15T12%3A00%3A00&outwardDateType=departAfter&journeySearchType=single&passengers%5B%5D=1991-06-15&selectedOutward=XWdk5x86R4c%3D%3AWFfBNL%2BcHPA%3D). If multiple people are travelling, a taxi may actually be the cheaper option.

As a public transport, and especially trains enthusiast, this would not be my preferred option, but for convenience it may be hard to beat.

Comment: It's an interesting point to compare the prices. Does 75 GBP cover a round trip?

Comment: For the prices referenced, both trips are a single. I'd guess you may be able to negotiate a return fare with the taxi firm if you only need a very brief time in Cambridge (it'd probably be worth the driver's time to wait 30 minutes and have a fare home than drive back 2h without a fare), but if it is a short-medium length trip (a few hours to a month) then a train return is likely to be cheaper.

Comment: Closely related option is other private car services, in particular ones that specialized in airport pickup/drop off as they are used to long journeys, including often being one way. I did cambridge<->oxford this way for a company event, and the company organized it exactly this way (OTOH, that might be because they hard a relationship with that airport shuttle car company, having used them many times for airports. But I don't think so, the driver seemed unsurprised at the trip.)

Comment: my God, is it 70+ quid to go from M.K. to cambridge these days on the train?  amazing eh

Comment: @Fattie much closer to £60 for an off peak walk-up fair, but as the question points out, the route suggested is effectively a long dog-leg through London, and thus close to pessimal for pricing purposes.

Comment: Go go gadget Tory focus on public transport!

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the correct ticket price for MK-Cambridge Off-Peak. I'm located in Berlin and the Trainline website was showing me prices in EUR, not in GBP (!)

Comment: The slower bus route is probably the cheapest alternative after all (but the question was fastest, not cheapest).

Comment: Not mentioned here is that the day return rail fare is 10p more, making it effectively £30 per direction if you're coming back same day. And the 1-month return is £75.20, which is still a significant saving over two singles. Walk-up singles have traditionally been poorly-priced in the UK for a long time now.

Comment: @origimbo  *. . . close to pessimal . . .*  What a lovely touch, that word. Almost a Cambridge maths don word. I take it we all agree on the restoration of the old Varsity Line as soon as possible ? Think of the convenience of it for many informal consultations between Oxbridge researchers !

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the taxi suggestion, depending on how long you're planning to spend in Cambridge, you may be better off actually hiring a car.  If you book in advance and spend some time searching, and don't need a large car, you may be able to get a car for under £40 a day. Even adding the cost of petrol, if you're going for a day, i.e. returning the within 24 hours of pickup, that may be fairly cheap and fast, too.

**EDIT:** To expand on Willeke's comment, liftshare.com is a good resource too. Have a look: https://liftshare.com/uk/search/from/milton-keynes - put "Cambridge, UK" as the destination and see if you can find a reasonable match. If you're going the other way, then start with https://liftshare.com/uk/search/from/cambridge and put Milton Keynes as the destination.

**EDIT 2:** To address the second of Willeke's comments, there are also car share schemes that you may be able to utilise.  Zip car is the most popular one, but there are also Virtuo, EasyCar club, E-Car club, Hiyacar and a number of others.  I haven't check which ones are available in Milton Keynes.

Comment: Are there car share services around there? Might be easier than rentals and can work out cheaper, especially if you need to do it more often.

Comment: I did not mean liftshare, but it is a good method. I meant a kind of rental cars which you can book, rent, unlock and pay for on your mobile phone, without having to go to an office to pick it up.

Comment: @Willeke it's not clear the OP can drive (in the UK).  As the question is locked I can't ask that, but I don't think it was in the comments before.

Comment: Those comments are still available, click on the link to the chatroom.

Comment: @Willeke that confirms my recollection: no one asked directly, and the OP didn't volunteer that information. .  They did however ask for public transport (which is also why I only commented about cycling part of the way, a solution that isn't great in this case anyway)

Answer (score 12):

> This really looks like a roundabout route.

The UK rail network is pretty London-centric and that area is particularly bad, In particular, once you leave London, there are no connections between the east coast and west coast mainlines until you reach the line that goes from Nuneaton to Peterborough (and on to Cambridge via Ely). From Milton Keynes that is an even more roundabout route than going via London. By rail Milton keynes to Nuneaton is around 47 miles, Nuneaton to Cambridge is around 116 miles, Milton Keynes to Euston is around 49 miles and Kings Cross to Cambridge is around 53 miles.

You can in principle get between the West and East coast mainlines in north London by taking the Watford DC line to Willesden junction, followed by the North London Line to Highbury & Islington and then the Northern City line to Finnsbury Park, but the extra interchanges and slower trains mean it is not a good choice compared to going into the city center.

Trains move significantly faster than even the fastest buses/coaches (both because of higher top speeds and because they don't have to deal with traffic), so even with a fast bus/coach service a roundabout train route can be time-competitive with a more direct bus/coach route. Add to that it appears from other answers that the fast direct bus has been cut back leaving only a regular local bus service for part of the route and it's not surprising that the train wins even with the roundabout route.

There is a currently ongoing project called "east west rail" which if/when it is eventually completed will link Oxford (served by a branch of the Great Western main line) to Norwich/Ipswich via Bicester (on the Chiltern main line), Bletchley (on the West coast main line), Bedford (on the Midland main line), Somewhere on the East coast main line in the St Neots/Sandy area and Cambridge effectively linking all the main lines north of London.

The Oxford to Bicester section of the route reopened in 2015, and the sections from Bletchley to Bedford and Cambridge to Norwich/Ipswich never closed. The section from Bicester to Bletchley is currently under construction.

However the Bedford to Cambridge section (referred to by east west rail as the "center section") is still in the consultation stages and is intended to be built on a completely new route because key parts of the old route have been lost to development, so don't expect it to open any time soon.

Comment: In France the rail network is pretty Paris-centered. (No surprise with such large, dominating capitals.) E.g. Villers-Cotterêts to Compiègne, a 27 km distance, is going through Paris according to Google maps and takes about as much time as the direct bike trip. Unfortunately the OP's route is too long (a bit under 80 km) to be competitive or even desirable with a bicycle.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Not just rail. Air travel too.